# How do I disable screensaver and systemd suspend on Ubuntu 20 from command-line or configuration files?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, screensaver

I have seen a lot of solutions about `gsettigns set` and `systemctl mask suspend.target ...` but none works for me.

My Ubuntu 20 has Gnome GUI. And the only thing I want is to completely disable screen to enter `sleep, suspend, hibernate, ...` states, i.e always active, always bright.

I want it to be done through the config files or command-line utilities (better is to manipulate with config files). What I have done so far and what doesn't work for me:

```
/etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/nosuspend.conf
```

Has the content of (as stated in https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend):

```
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=no
AllowHibernation=no
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no
AllowHybridSleep=no
```

And I also run these two commands in a command-line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

The best result I have achieved is that GUI screen is always bright, however the `Automatic suspend` warning by the system still appears after some amount of time and then (in a couple of minutes) the screen is sleeping and black.